# Can a "Not your code" default off-topic option be added to the close dialog?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, vote-to-close, close-dialog

A number of questions have come up recently where the code is not the asker's own code, prompting a 'close' response. It would be convenient if there was an 'off-topic' close option that included:

> off-topic because the code you want reviewed is not **your** code. See the [help (item 2) for on-topic posts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

link points to `https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic`

Comment: Totally agree. Actually each point in the on-topicness checklist should be a default close reason.

Comment: There can only be three custom close reasons at this time and we are using all of them already, so this can't currently be done. Feel free to suggest replacing one of the other reasons with this one, but I don't think it's common enough to warrant deactivating one of the others.

Comment: @codesparkle: Is that just a beta thing?  SO has five custom close reasons.

Comment: @Jamal this limit applies to all sites with specific exceptions (not sure if there are any except for Stack Overflow) as explained [in this MSO answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185097/175128). I'm not convinced that there's an urgent enough need for this to warrant asking for an exception though. The wording of the proposed new close reason also leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @codesparkle: Thanks for the link.  While it's an okay close reason, I do agree that the active three are more common.

Comment: @codesparkle - If the wording was better would it help? I only ask because I think that, with minor changes, the first two off-topic close options are really just one - `to review code we need to have working code...`

Comment: I would like to point out that linking to the *on-topic* page is as easy as `[help/on-topic]`: [help/on-topic].